# LIKE operator in SSRS row visibility expression

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2008, visibility, sql-like

I have a text box within an rdl report which I want to suppress based on certain terms in my dataset (i.e. if the query returns a term which ends with the letter "L" then hide the text box).

Within the textbox properties I have set visibility expression for Hidden with the below expression:

```
=First(Fields!STERMS__.Value, "Job") NOT LIKE '%L'
```

When I run it I get the error:

> "The Visibility.Hidden expression for the text box contains an error:
>   [BC30201] Expression expected"

It seems like a schoolboy error but I have tried various permutations on this expression with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS expressions are funny in some ways. I think what you're looking for is:

```
=IIf(First(Fields!STERMS__.Value, "Job") Like "*L", True, False)
```

The gist is that SSRS doesn't use SQL syntax. It's VB

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the Right() function which returns a specified number of characters from the right hand side of a string.

E.g.

```
=Right(Fields!STERMS__.Value,1)
```

I guess in your case for Hidden property on the cell, the expression would look like this

```
=IIF(Right(First(Fields!STERMS__.Value, "Job"),1)=="L",true,false)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to amend your expression as the duplicated equals sign was still giving the same error. Apart from that, spot on.